# MySQL - Выборка из 3 таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 3 таблицы, testing,lessons,course.

Хочу вывести колонки id из testing, title из lessons который соотвествует id колонки lesson_id из таблицы testing.И колонку name из таблицы course для этого урока, для определения курса урока в таблице lessons есть колонка course_id.

Начал пробовать, составил такой запрос

```
SELECT *, (SELECT `course_id` FROM `lessons` WHERE id=testing.id) as `course_id` FROM `testing` ORDER BY id ASC
```

выводит не правильные данные, id курса не соотвует уроку (на скрине отметил результат).

Не совсем понимаю как правильно составить запрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE 1:**
Заметил свою ошибку почему id курса не соответствовал уроку

```
SELECT *, (SELECT `course_id` FROM `lessons` WHERE testing.lesson_id = lessons.id) as `course_id` FROM `testing` ORDER BY id ASC
```

пожалуй нужно отдохнуть немного)

Comment: Прочитай про `JOIN`-ы и попробуй с их помощью составить запрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам следует составлять запрос с использованием JOIN, а не подзапросов, так гораздо проще:

```
SELECT testing.test, lessons.title, course.name
FROM testing
    JOIN lessons ON testing.lesson_id = lessons.id
    JOIN course ON lessons.course_id = course.id
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду читать сегодня про джоины, попрактикусь еще :)