# Выборка из 3 таблиц mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Помогите реализовать выборку из 3 таблиц.
Есть 3 таблицы:

1. news
   `id|title|body|author|category`
2. categories
   `id|title`
3. users
   `id|login`

В таблице `news` есть поле `author` и `category`, числовые, указывающие на `id` к другим двум таблицам. В данный момент у меня циклом выводятся новости вместе с пагинацией. Но мне надо ещё цеплять по id из двух других таблиц название категории, к которой относится новость и логин юзера, чья новость.

Comment: Приведите пример ваших выборок. Что у вас конкретно не получается?

Comment: У меня нету примеров. Я недавно изучаю php и mysql и реализовать такой сложный запрос мне пока не по силам.

Comment: @Ilya так, быть может, надо изучить в начале, потренироваться, а потом что-то делать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский То есть по вашему я должен изучать язык программирования теоретический, а не сидя в редакторе и клепая код? В данный момент я дошёл до того что не могу реализовать данный запрос, который мне необходим и мне нужна помощь в этой проблеме. Если вам нечем помочь, прошу пройти мимо, мне на другие темы есть с кем пообщаться.

Comment: @Ilya сайт создан, чтобы чему-то научить человека, а не сделать за него.  В каждой книге по SQL есть раздел JOIN, он и есть ответ на Ваш вопрос. Всегда надо начинать обучение с чтения книг.

Comment: @Ilya да,  в начале люди читают книги (в которых, как правило, есть примеры на каждую главу и которые можно протестировать, а также задания для практического ощупывания), осваивают основы и теории, особенности, конструкции, а затем пробуют с этим багажом что-то делать.  Что-то у меня сомнения на счет того, что автомобили Toyota сразу бегут собирать не зная ничего, а только в процессе начинают изучать как это делается и что для этого нужно, что-куда тыкать и что нажать

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Понять не могу, откуда столько желчи. Я не пришёл просить написать за меня реализацию моего скрипта. Я лишь попросил помощи в составлении запроса, который я не могу реализовать на данном этапе развития в этой области. Если нечем мне помочь, зачем что-то мне говорить не по теме и минусить? У вас от этого ЧСВ повышается? Я сомневаюсь что вы разбираетесь в теме которая касается моего вопроса. Прошу проходить мимо таких "больших специалистов".

Comment: У вас нет примеров ??? Вы же на стаковерфлоу. Если в поиск вверху сайта вбить "из 3 таблиц" (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B8%D0%B7+3+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86) то сразу находите массу примеров. Даже можно в поиск не вбивать, на странице с вашим вопросом справа ссылки на похожие вопросы ... причем примеры там как раз для вашего случая, только имена таблиц подставить ваши и все

Comment: @Ilya я Вам уже написал читайте про Sql JOIN.

Comment: @Ilya Не надо видеть негатив, вместо банального совета. Если вы не удосужились немного ознакомиться с теорией - это не вина остальных. Минусов от меня лично не было, но теперь, возможно, за хамство, он будет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [MySQL - Выборка из 3 таблиц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590092/mysql-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-3-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86)

Comment: И кстати по любому справочнику SQL до такого уровня изучается часа за 3 максимум.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [соединение таблиц](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html) `join`:

```
select n.title, n.body,
    c.title as category_title,
    u.login
from news n
    join categories c on n.category = c.id
    join users u on n.author = u.id
```

<sub>Оффтоп: Такие вопросы, на самом деле, повторяются из раза в раз на ruSO, поэтому на ваш вопрос не дали ответа. Как правильно заметил Mike, даже на самом ruSO эти вопросы встречались не один раз, к тому же соединение таблиц - несложная тема, на чье разбирательство уйдёт не так много времени.</sub>

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь!